# Code and table formatting sandbox

Tags: discussion, formatting

Use this post a sandbox for formatted code and tables. You can also use [an online tool](https://donatstudios.com/CsvToMarkdownTable) to generate these kinds of tables.

#### Tables

```
╔══════════════╦════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ Country Code ║ Prefix ║ Currency Code ║ Time Zone (GMT) ║
╠══════════════╬════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ GBR          ║ +44    ║ GBP           ║               0 ║
╚══════════════╩════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════╝

+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+
| Country Code | Prefix | Currency Code | Time Zone (GMT) |
+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+
| GBR          | +44    | GBP           |               0 |
+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+
```

#### Testing html tags in markdown environments

> foobardfoo 
>   linebreak 'br' works here

```
foobardfoo <br />
linebreak 'br' doesn't here
```

Comment: There's also a helpful online tool: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: @JonathanReez I was waiting for you to post that. I couldn't find the other question on which you did.

Answer (score 2):

```
████████╗██████╗  █████╗ ██╗   ██╗███████╗██╗     
╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║   ██║██╔════╝██║     
   ██║   ██████╔╝███████║██║   ██║█████╗  ██║     
   ██║   ██╔══██╗██╔══██║╚██╗ ██╔╝██╔══╝  ██║     
   ██║   ██║  ██║██║  ██║ ╚████╔╝ ███████╗███████╗
   ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝  ╚═══╝  ╚══════╝╚══════╝

   ███████╗███████╗                               
   ██╔════╝██╔════╝                               
   ███████╗█████╗                                 
   ╚════██║██╔══╝                                 
██╗███████║███████╗                               
╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝                               

    (
   (_)
   ###       .
   (#c    __\|/__
    #\     wWWWw
    \ \-. (/. .\)
    /\ /`\/\   /\
    |\/   \_) (_|
    `\.' ; ; `' ;`\
      `\;  ;    .  ;/\
        `\;    ;  ;|  \
         ;   .'  ' ;  /
         |_.'   ;  | /)
         (     ''._;/`
         |    ' . ;
         |.-'   .:)
         |        |
         (  .'  : |
         |,-  .:: |
         | ,-'  .;|
     jgs_/___,_.:_\_
       [I_I_I_I_I_I_]
       | __________ |
       | || |  | || |
      _| ||_|__|_|| |_
     /=--------------=\
    /                  \
   |                    |
```